# Convert list into Array

Tags: java, android, arrays

I want to create a String Array with all URLs in the list.

I have a list of URLs stored in a list object `myUrlList`. Using `myUrlList.toString();` returns a `String` in the form `[http://url1, http://url2, http://url3.....]`.

Also, `myUrlList.getSize()` returns correctly the number of URLs the list contains.

How can I obtain an array of all the URLs in the list? I tried `myUrlList.toArray`, `(String[]) myUrlList.toArray()`, and others with no success. It is not even possible to obtain one element using`myUrlList.get(position)`.

Comment: A few questions: What have you tried? What type of list are you working with? Can you post some code?

Comment: if size() returns a value you should be able to use get(position) of an index less than size... Also maybe try myUrlList.toArray(new String[0])

Comment: My list returns files from an http server:

Comment: The list returns file list of a http server. ApacheURLLister lister1 = new ApacheURLLister();         
                List myUrlList = lister1.listAll(url);

Answer (score 5):

You can convert a List (ArrayList, LinkedList, etc.) to an array simply by using the toArray() method, like this:

```
List<URL> list = new ArrayList<URL>();
URL[] array = list.toArray(new URL[0]);
```